# remove data-image attribute class when I new click

Tags: javascript

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.pill').on("click", function(){

    var img = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('.simplified-for a span').text(getText);

    $(".img").toggleClass(img);
});
```

});

Comment: use $('.pill').removeAttr('data-img'); in your **new click** funtion

Comment: @atomankion thank you! but when I add this $('.pill').removeAttr('data-img'); all the classes are removed but I need to remove only previous class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: than toggle class is the solution

Comment: @Ethan thank you as I want to tell you that all I need is when clicking a first time on the button the class added to the one taken div and again when I trigger the new button that first-class needs to remove and add that second class which is on a new button thats all I need.